# Why doesn't my listbox print array elements?

Tags: vb.net

So I'm working on a project for class that I can't understand the error in my code. I have looked over it till I'm blue in the face. Any help in understanding is greatly appreciated. I'm trying to load values into an array and have that array print the values in the list box in a 2nd form.

```
Private Sub displayStd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles displayStd.Click

    Dim fmtStr As String = "{0,-10}{1,10}{2,15}{3,20}{4,25}"
    Dim form As New Form2()
    form.displayLB.Items.Clear()
    form.displayLB.Items.Add("There are " & Student.Count & " accounts.")
    form.displayLB.Items.Add(String.Format(fmtStr, "ID", "Name", "Score1", "Score2", "Average Score"))


    For Each studentObj As Student In students
        form.displayLB.Items.Add(String.Format(fmtStr, studentObj.ID,
        studentObj.Name, studentObj.Score1, studentObj.Score2, studentObj.CalculateAverage(studentObj.Score1, studentObj.Score2)))
    Next
    form.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

I'm getting:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in Student Record.exe
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

highlighting this as an error:

```
form.displayLB.Items.Add(String.Format(fmtStr, studentObj.ID,
            studentObj.Name, studentObj.Score1, studentObj.Score2, studentObj.CalculateAverage(studentObj.Score1, studentObj.Score2)))
```

CalculateAvg method:

```
Public Function CalculateAverage(score1 As Integer, score2 As Integer)

        Dim sum As Double
        Dim avg As Double


        sum = score1 + score2
        avg = sum / 2

        Return avg


    End Function
```

Student class:

```
Public Class Student

    Private IDVALUE As String
    Private nameValue As String
    Private score1Value As Integer
    Private score2Value As Integer
    Private Shared studentCount As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As String, ByVal name As String, ByVal score1 As Integer, ByVal score2 As Integer)

        IDVALUE = id
        nameValue = name
        score1Value = score1
        score2Value = score2
    End Sub

    Public Property ID As String


        Get
            Return IDVALUE
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            IDVALUE = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name As String


        Get
            Return nameValue
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            nameValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Score1 As Integer


        Get
            Return score1Value
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            score1Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Score2 As Integer


        Get
            Return score2Value
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            score2Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Property Count() As Integer

        Get
            Return studentCount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            studentCount = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function CalculateAverage(score1 As Integer, score2 As Integer)

        Dim sum As Double
        Dim avg As Double


        sum = score1 + score2
        avg = sum / 2

        Return avg


    End Function

End Class
```

Form1 Class:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim students As Student()

    Private Sub addStd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addStd.Click
        Dim thisStudent As New Student(idTB.Text, nameTB.Text, CInt(score1TB.Text), CInt(score2TB.Text))

        ReDim Preserve students(Student.Count + 1)
        students(Student.Count + 1) = thisStudent

        idTB.Text = ""
        nameTB.Text = ""
        score1TB.Text = ""
        score2TB.Text = ""
    End Sub
Private Sub displayStd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles displayStd.Click

        Dim fmtStr As String = "{0,-10}{1,10}{2,15}{3,20}{4,25}"
        Dim form As New Form2()
        form.displayLB.Items.Clear()
        form.displayLB.Items.Add("There are " & Student.Count & " accounts.")
        form.displayLB.Items.Add(String.Format(fmtStr, "ID", "Name", "Score1", "Score2", "Average Score"))


        For Each studentObj As Student In students
            form.displayLB.Items.Add(String.Format(fmtStr, studentObj.ID,
            studentObj.Name, studentObj.Score1, studentObj.Score2, studentObj.CalculateAverage(studentObj.Score1, studentObj.Score2)))
        Next
        form.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you check the `CalculateAverage()` method in your `Student` class? Or could you show that method also here?

Comment: If you look at your code where you load the `students` collection you will find it, but you will have to show us or we can't help. Either the `students` collection is not declared as `New` or the `student` objects are not declared with `New`.

Comment: Where/how do you declare the collection? How do you fill it?

Comment: @DonA included the whole form1 class so you can see the whole code.

Comment: @DonA is there something wrong with how I fill it?

Comment: No, how you initialize it is wrong.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line of code and when it hits, hover your cursor over each variable and check which one is null (Nothing).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `List(of T)` instead of array like this:

Change this:

```
Dim students As Student()
```

To:

```
Dim students As New List(Of Student)
```

And this one :

```
Private Sub addStd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addStd.Click
    Dim thisStudent As New Student(idTB.Text, nameTB.Text, CInt(score1TB.Text), CInt(score2TB.Text))

    ReDim Preserve students(Student.Count + 1)
    students(Student.Count + 1) = thisStudent

    idTB.Text = ""
    nameTB.Text = ""
    score1TB.Text = ""
    score2TB.Text = ""
End Sub
```

To this one:

```
Private Sub addStd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addStd.Click
    Dim thisStudent As New Student(idTB.Text, nameTB.Text, CInt(score1TB.Text), CInt(score2TB.Text))

    students.Add(thisStudent)

    idTB.Text = ""
    nameTB.Text = ""
    score1TB.Text = ""
    score2TB.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Now, if you want to use Array then I think you need to `overload` your `New`'ing, like:

```
Public Sub New()

End Sub
```

Then you could now instantiate like this:

```
Dim students As New Student()
```

Because you could not instantiate in your case without the need to put values on the parameters of your `New(ByVal id As String, ByVal name As String, ByVal score1 As Integer, ByVal score2 As Integer)`.

Comment: Sorry the instructions state it has to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize the Student array.

```
Dim students As Student()
```

Should be;

```
Dim students() As Student = New Student() {} 'empty array
```

ReDim part;

```
ReDim Preserve students(Student.Count)
students(Student.Count - 1) = thisStudent
```

Comment: thanks for helping me fix that, but that doesn't solve my error I'm still getting.